Does ¼” #10 clean rock settle as much as sand as a patio base?
When using sand as the bedding layer of a paver patio, during final compacting the pavers will settle 1/4-3/8". This settling needs to be taken into account when figuring the height of the base gravel layer and where the final height of the patio will end up.
My question has to do with screeding ¼" #10 clean rock instead of sand for the bedding layer. Since this is rock, I am assuming that it will not compact and the pavers will not settle at all during the final compacting. Is this true?

I don't understand '1/4 - 10" clean rock '. This is the range of rock sizes that you are bedding on?

https://landscapeshoppe.com/product/1-4-10-open/

You're adding the double quotation mark in the wrong place, which is confusing. It's 1/4" and 10 something else, not 10 inches. In this case it's #10, which is the final screening size in many cases, including sand and dust. So 1/4" #10, or #10 product screened to 1/4". The phrase "#10 clean" would therefore seem contradictory. I suspect that you're really just asking about 1/4" screen, and not #10.

Are you talking about AASHTO #10 aggregate?

Locally, this is known as bedding stone. Just bought some for one of my own projects. It will compress by about 10% once applied. A 3" base will lose about 5/16" of an inch, in this case.
However, the way I have applied in the past is to put it down as a base of about 3", water it down and then apply a thin layer of sand on top to bed the pavers. I then went over it with a plate compactor to set. Hasn't moved in 14 years.

So, a 1" layer would compress somewhere between 1/16th and 1/8th of an inch (using the normal markings on a measuring tape).

Assuming the sand is dry, yes.
